Find the sum $PC^2+PD^2$ in the trapezoid inscribed below
If there is a semicircle of diameter $AB$ in which an isosceles trapezoid $ABCD$, ($AB \parallel CD$) is inscribed. On $AB$, we take a point "$P$" such that $PA^2 + PB^2 = 5^2$.
Calculate: $PC^2 + PD^2$.
I made the drawing and tried it.

$\triangle ADP: PD^2 = l^2+PA^2 - 2lPA\cos\theta\ (I)$
$\triangle PCB: PC^2 = l^2+PB^2 - 2lPB\cos\theta\ (II)$
$(I)+(II):\ PC^2+PD^2 = 2l^2+PA^2+PB^2-2l\cos\theta(PA+PB)$
$\underbrace{PC^2+PD^2} =2l^2+ 25-2l\cos\theta(PA+PB)$
$\underbrace{PC^2+PD^2} =2l^2+ 25-2l\cos\theta(2R)$
I couldn't finish it....

You've made a great start. Actually, you almost have it!
Add $OC$, label the midpoint of $BC$ as $M$, and add $OM$. Since $\triangle OBC$ is isosceles (due to $\lvert OB\rvert = \lvert OC\rvert = R$), we have $\measuredangle OMB = 90^{\circ}$. Thus, with $\triangle OBM$, since $\lvert BM\rvert = \frac{l}{2}$, we get
$$\cos\theta = \frac{\lvert BM\rvert}{\lvert OB\rvert} = \frac{\frac{l}{2}}{R} = \frac{l}{2R} \;\;\to\;\; 2l\cos\theta(2R) = 4lR\left(\frac{l}{2R}\right) = 2l^2$$
Using your result then gives
$$\lvert PC\rvert^2 + \lvert PD\rvert^2 = 2l^2 + 25 - 2l\cos\theta(2R) = 2l^2 + 25 - 2l^2 = 25$$

Let $\overline {\text {AP}} = a$, $\overline {\text {BP}} = b$, $\overline {\text {CP}} = c$, and $\overline {\text {DP}} = d$. Let $\overline {\text {AO}} = r$ and $\overline {\text {PO}} = \delta$, so $a = r - \delta$ and $b = r + \delta$. That is to say, $r = \left( a + b \right) / \, 2$ and $\delta = \left( b - a \right) / \, 2$; we will use these results. Let $\angle \text {AOD} = \theta$. Then, by the law of cosines, we have
$$
\begin{align}
{c}^{2} & = {r}^{2} + {\delta}^{2} + 2 r \delta \cos \left( \theta \right), \\
{d}^{2} & = {r}^{2} + {\delta}^{2} - 2 r \delta \cos \left( \theta \right).
\end{align}
$$
Accordingly, we find that
$$
\begin{align}
{c}^{2} + {d}^{2}
& = 2 \left( {r}^{2} + {\delta}^{2} \right) \\
& = 2 \left( {\Big( \frac {a + b}{2} \Big)}^{2} + {\Big( \frac {b - a}{2} \Big)}^{2} \right) \\
& = 2 \left( \frac {{a}^{2} + 2 a b + {b}^{2}}{4} + \frac {{b}^{2} - 2 a b + {a}^{2}}{4} \right)
= {a}^{2} + {b}^{2}.
\end{align}
$$
${a}^{2} + {b}^{2} = 25$ specifically in your case.


Let $AB=PA+PB=2r$ and $h$ be the distance between parallel sides $AB$ and $CD$. Also, $DA=CB=\ell$ and $\angle CBP=\angle DAB=\theta$. Draw $DM\perp AP$. We have $AM=\ell\cos\theta$ and $h=\ell\sin\theta$.
By the geometric mean theorem in the right-angled $\triangle DAB$, $h^2=\ell^2\sin^2\theta=AM\cdot MB=\ell\cos\theta\cdot(2r-\ell\cos\theta)=2r\ell\cos\theta-\ell^2\cos^2\theta\implies\color{red}{\ell=2r\cos\theta}$.
$\color{red}{\ell=2r\cos\theta}$ can also be derived by $OQ\perp BC$, and then $\cos\theta=\frac{\ell/2}{r}\implies\ell=2r\cos\theta$, which can be used to prove the geometric mean theorem.
Now, draw $PN\perp DC$, and from the right-angled $\triangle DNP$ and $\triangle CNP$
$$\begin{aligned}
PC^2+PD^2&=2h^2+(PA-\ell\cos\theta)^2+(PB-\ell\cos\theta)^2\\&=2\ell^2\sin^2\theta+PA^2+PB^2-2\ell\cos\theta(PA+PB)+2\ell^2\cos^2\theta\\&=2\ell^2(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)+5^2-2\ell\cdot\color{red}{2r\cos\theta}\\&=2\ell^2+25-2\ell^2\\&=25
\end{aligned}$$
Hence, ${PC^2+PD^2=25}$.
I hope this helps!

@petaarantes You're most welcome! I have used the Pythagorean theorem, so more steps! The laws of cosines reduce the steps. My solution also includes the derivation of the cosine laws.
